# Constraint against a median

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm trying to solve a satisfiabilty problem over integers using z3py where one of my constraints requires that the value of each variable in an array be greater than the median of the last eleven variables.  Right now, I'm encoding the constraint like:

> PbLe( ((v[i] <= v[i-11],1),...(v[i] <= v[i-1],1)), 6)

And this seems to be causing the solver to use a tremendous amount of memory. I assume the PbLe is getting converted to disjunctive normal form on the backend or something similar and causing a large blowup in the size of the expression.

Is there a more efficient way to express a 'greater than a rolling median' for values in an array in z3?

Comment: What's the rule for the first eleven variables in the array? do they have a smaller-sized window or no constraint at all? What's the domain of these variables? Are these integers or real numbers?

Comment: A minimal example for us to play with would help!

Comment: patrick trentin:   Integers, the first value is defined to be equal to 0 the next 10 are just constrained to be >0, after that the subsequent ones are constrained to be greater than the rolling median.  I'll extract out some example code and post it.

Comment: The `PbLe()` constraint may benefit from using a *sorting network* with 11 inputs and 7 outputs. However, this can only mitigate the performance problem (at best). This is one of those situations in which the use of bit-vectors (of the smallest size possible) for the variables `v[i]` could be handy, for their better propagation properties. Even so, it may still explode in memory. Strengthening the constraint could make wonders (e.g. `v[i] larger than every value in the sliding window`), but perhaps this is not compatible with the application you have in mind.

Comment: Using the *integer* encoding, if the reference inequality was of the form `v[0] <= v[11]`, then I would think that perhaps adding constraints of the form `v[0] <= v[11] => v[0] <= v[12], etc.` may help the SAT engine to identify conflicting assignments at the Boolean level earlier in the search, without discovering these conflicts at run-time and learning them one-by-one. This might or might not help, it also depends on how many of this type of constraints you may end up adding.

Comment: Another thing to check is whether it is possible to set the *preferred variables for branching* (a.k.a. *preferred decision variables*) and their *initial phase-saving* value. It looks like it would help telling the \smt solver to assign the values `v[i]` in increasing order. Or, alternatively, do this incrementally (if allowed by the applicaiton). Extend `v[i]` by one more value at each **incremental** `\smt.check()` and, if necessary to keep the memory usage low, replace the latest `PbLe()` with the model value of `v[i]` after each step so that T-lemmas depending on `PbLe()` are discarded.

Comment: did you try something?